# Possible to create an enum type at runtime?

Tags: c++11, boost, dynamic

Is it possible to do the following in C++11?

```
int NED = 3;
```

or more likely,

```
struct EnumMembers
{
   std::string name;
};


list<EnumMembers> countries = readafileOfMembers();

say countries list contains "USA", "NOR";

enum CountryType
{
};

for(auto& c : countries)
{
    CountryType.Add(c); //since USA first added = 0
}
```

or I can say:

```
CountryType.Add(NED);

CountryType c = CountryType::USA;
```

Essentially, enum is a container that must be filled at compile time. I want an enum that can be filled dynamically at runtime.
Maybe I am not really looking for an enum, but a dynamic type that acts like an enum.

Comment: you can create a struct that models an integer, but does the extra domain validations underneath. I have not seen such a thing before. (in C++), standardized

Comment: C++ is a statically typed compiled language. You cannot do that sort of thing. The closest you can come at is to use a map to lookup integer values from string keys.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is depends on usage of it. But it's not enum for sure. You need dynamic data structure as `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, maybe `std::set` you can search for example usages of `std::set` for example:

```
enum class Countries
{
  USA =0,
  Canada =1
};


std::set<Countries> countries;
countries.insert(Countries::USA);
countreis.insert(Countries::Canada);
```

Or you can use `unordered_map` when integer value should be related to countries...

Comment: No that is not what I want. Either I didn't explain it very well, or you not understanding what I am asking for. std::set<Countries> countries adds no extra value over the already created enum type Countries. An enum adds type safety over an int. I want to be able to create an enum type at runtime so that members are not known at compile time, and I want the semantics of an enum.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your comment I understand your requirements as follows:

- You need to impose additional type safety by restricting the range of legal values
- You want to determine the range of legal values at runtime

In a statically typed language like c++ where all the type checking happens at compile time these two requirements are mutually exclusive. (Compare that to a dynamically typed language where such an approach would be feasible).

However, note that the best you can achieve even with dynamic typing would be runtime validation of invariants (e.g. in python you'd get a TypeError exception). You could obviously mimick this behaviour by storing the countries in a dynamic datastructure as proposed by Bartosz and creating a custom class as follows:

```
class Country {
   Country (int numericRepresentation)
     : numericRepresentation(numericRepresentation)
   {
      // setOfLegalInputs could be static
      if(!setOfLegalInputs.contains(numericRepresentation)
      {
          throw TypeError("No such country exists");
      }
   }

   // ...
}
```